# Magento shows wrong special price (frontend)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We have updated to the latest Magento version 1.9.1.1 and everything works so far except one thing. Instead of showing the real special price, every product has the same price (20.00) in every product (catalog view & product view). Yesterday the prices were correct.
In the Magento backend everything seems to be as it should. We've changed the template back to default to see if it has an impact but it doesn't make any difference. Price index is already up-to-date. Example:

Backend:
[image: Magento backend product price]

Frontend:
[image]

Comment: this can cause this issue: `Promotions -> Catalog price rules` and a rule there to put all products on discount. also do you have multistore?

Comment: OMG I was checking almost every file for a mistake and even the database until I checked the 'Catalog price rules'. Someone added this to the dev environment. :-/ Thank you very much!